# sony vaio vpcy21s1e black screen

Tags: graphics, laptop, compatibility, sony

I've seen this post on the linuxmint forums on a laptop model I'm interested in:
http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=77810
I would like to know if anyone got this or similar laptop model working on Ubuntu Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because of a SoftEDID issue (I've had this issue before).

I'll find a link that explains the problem/solution and post it here -- you need to extract your EDID data in Windows and modify xorg.conf.

---

#### Updates:

See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaOnSonyLaptop) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1369420.html).